# Query RaspberryPi and display data on client side in HTML page

Tags: python-3.x, flask, raspberry-pi

I need to fetch data from RaspberryPi and display on the HTML page, so far I've managed to set up RaspberryPi (as server-wirelessly) and my laptop (as client) and fetch RaspberryPi's features.
I want to display those features on a HTML page

I'm using Ubuntu terminal on my laptop to execute client side code

client.py

```
import socket

HOST = "192.168.1.1"  # The server's hostname or IP address
PORT = 65432  # The port used by the server

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    s.sendall(b"Hello, world")
    data = s.recv(1024)

print(f"Received {data!r}")
s.close()
```

server.py

```
import socket
from vcgencmd import Vcgencmd


HOST = "192.168.1.1"  # Standard loopback interface address (localhost)
PORT = 65432  # Port to listen on (non-privileged ports are > 1023)

core_volts = str(vcgm.measure_volts("core"))
#
    with conn:
        print(f"Connected by {addr}")
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            if not data:
                break
            conn.sendall(core_volts.encode())
```

results

```
ms@G1g1-v0L1R:~/client$ python3 client.py
Received b"Aug  9 2022 13:44:40 0.88
```

0.88 is core volts fetched from RaspberryPi

I want HTML button **Fetch Core Volts** (it should execute client.py) and in turn fetch Core Volts from RaspberryPi and display on HTML page.
Can this be done using flask? If so, how. Any other pointers, please suggest.

Comment: Yes, it can be done using Flask. Read the documentation, it'll tell you how to do it. There are also over 50,000 questions tagged [tag:flask] on Stack Overflow, not to mention all the other results from your search engine of choice. There's plenty of information already out there.

Comment: appreciate your response @MattDMo, out of these 50,000 could you point me to relevant ones, please note that I'm also trying to search at my end

Comment: Stack Overflow is neither a discussion forum nor a tutorial, code-writing, or homework service. This is a Q&A site where *specific* programming questions (usually, but not always, including some code) get *specific* answers. Please take the [tour] and carefully read through the [help] to learn more about the site, including [ask], as well as [what is on-topic](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [what is not](//stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Please also follow the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648).

Comment: Find some good tutorials on Flask, follow them, and I think you'll get it pretty quickly.